# Почему нет тире перед обобщающим словом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, обобщающее-слово

Маленький вопрос. **Добавлен для ясности содержания текст.**

*Выбежал Ластик из подъезда во двор своего замечательного дома, по привычке повертел головой влево-вправо. Слева за решеткой чернел квадратной пастью уже упомянутый въезд в подвалы, справа серела подворотня, тоже квадратная. И там, в подворотне, Ластик вдруг увидел силуэт, показавшийся ему очень знакомым. Какой-то мальчик стоял там, в густой тени, и, прислонившись к стене, смотрел в эту сторону.*

*Так ведь это я, это мое отражение, понял вдруг Ластик. Вон и куртка красного цвета!*

*Но какое в подворотне может быть отражение?* ***Там ни зеркала, ни витрины, ничего.***

*Ластик зажмурился, потому что если зажмуриться, а после разожмуриться обратно, видно гораздо лучше.*

*Но когда он снова открыл глаза, двойник исчез. Осталась одна пустая подворотня.*

*Это называется «зрительная галлюцинация», сказал себе Ластик – когда видишь то, чего на самом деле нет. И обрадовался, потому что галлюцинаций у него отродясь не бывало.*

*Он решил, что поразмыслит над загадочным явлением после, во время урока, а сейчас некогда – в школу опоздаешь.* (Б. Акунин)

Почему **нет тире** перед местоимением "ничего"? Авторская пунктуация?

А какой знак (по слуху и по правилам) поставили бы вы?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146622/discussion-on-question-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

**Комментарий**

***Там ни зеркала, ни витрины, ничего.***

1. Фраза Акунина не казалась мне некорректной, и не **было желания поставить тире.** Почему? Автор выбрал перечислительную интонацию и включил «ничего» **в общий однородный ряд**. Это внутренний монолог героя, который в чем-то похож на поток сознания, долгие паузы  там ни к чему. При этом основной вариант (по правилам) «*Там ни зеркала, ни витрины – ничего*» тоже **возможен**, но здесь присоединительная интонация.

Кстати, это **обычный прием на письме** – упрощение синтаксиса, а не принципиальный вопрос вроде «***быть или не быть***».  Мы условно заменяем осложненные отношения более простыми.

**Дополнение от 12.06.2023 в 12.30**

**В качестве аргументации.** Здесь просматривается **однозначное соответствие:** поставили **запятые** – интонация перечислительная (иначе не прочитаешь) – это однородные отношения (**вывод**).

2. Но при обсуждении темы я обратила внимание **на само местоимение «ничего».** Можно ли считать, что в а заданном предложении  это не обобщающее слово?  Вроде бы да, если представить его в такой форме: *ничего отражающего, никаких отражающих поверхностей.*  А «ничего» – это просто неполная запись этой формы. Тогда слово **на законных основаниях** вписывается в ряд.
3. Любопытным показалось мне обсуждение **самого текста.** Что-нибудь в нем не так? Повествование ведется от 3-го лица, что видно **по вводным словам** (понял, сказал себе), которые являются аналогами слов автора.

Но есть одна интересная деталь: наше предложение записано в отдельный абзац, так что не очень ясно, относится ли вводное сочетание «понял вдруг Ластик» к предыдущей фразе или нет. И тогда это предложение очень похоже **на несобственно-прямую речь.**

**Спасибо всем**, кто принял и принимает участие в этом интересном обсуждении темы.

**ДЛЯ СПРАВОК:**

Несобственно-прямая речь (НПР)  – это часть текста, передающая **слова, мысли, чувства** персонажа, которая оформлена особым образом. НПР совмещает свойства прямой и косвенной  (авторской) речи. Этот прием часто используется в художественной литературе и публицистике, когда автору нужно показать своего героя **как бы изнутри**, дать читателю услышать его **внутренний голос**.

Приём несобственно-прямой речи впервые использовал в русской литературе А. С. Пушкин, после чего он получил развитие в художественной литературе.

**Текстовый пример:** «*Но вот его комната. Ничего и никого, никто не заглядывал. Даже Настасья не притрагивалась. Но, Господи! Как мог он оставить давеча все эти вещи в этой дыре? Он бросился в угол, запустил руку под обои и стал вытаскивать вещи и нагружать ими карманы»*  (Ф. Достоевский).

Comment: Докажите, что однородный ряд. Никаких показателей однородности нет. Союз "и" должен подходить, это железно. В примерах по данному правилу нет присоединения (и присоединительной интонации), не знаю, чего у вас присоединительная, когда тире. В плане прямой речи там авторская пунктуация. Ничего подобного в материалах по НПР не вижу. Может быть, чем известнее писатель, тем больше он чувствует вседозволенность.

Comment: Из официальных текстов:  Сегодня, 12 июня 2023 года, наша страна отмечает большой государственный праздник "День России".  Ну и лето скоро, птички в лесу поют... И поэтому, пожалуйста, не сердитесь на меня...

Comment: Нельзя сказать, что сержусь, потому что называние неоднородного однородным не очень критично, у вас были вещи гораздо похуже. Хотелось бы от вас более научного подхода, позитивного отношения к критике, как было раньше, и особенно реакции на неё (в лучшем случае это корректировка ответа). В лингвистике надо быть очень осторожным и точным. А вы нередко говорите как бы что попало.

Comment: В НПР лица не меняются, там автор говорит вместо персонажа, и близко не похоже.

Comment: Спасибо за откровенность, буду работать над собой, хотя бы по праздникам))  (1) Сейчас добавлю  АРГУМЕНТАЦИЮ  для значения однородности в ответ.  (2) В НПР лица не меняются относительно КОСВЕННОЙ речи (3-е лицо), но в тексте используется 1-е лицо в ПРЯМОЙ речи (где есть вводные слова в качестве слов автора).

Comment: Они не однородные, нельзя доказать, что 2 + 2 = 5, просто присоединение иногда похоже на это, а именно интонация похожая. Не вижу в примерах первого лица. Здесь не вводные слова, здесь чисто слова автора.

Comment: Сравните произношение: *Там нет ни первого, ни второго, ни третьего. Там нет ни первого, ни второго, ничего.* Оно не одинаковое. Звучит неправильно, если произнести "ничего" так, как "ни третьего".

Comment: Ваши аргументы не принимаются (без комментариев)) Уезжаю, уезжаю... Обсудите с другими участниками. Пока...

Comment: Вот за это реально можно сердиться (особенно за непринимание).